# Install Fedora20 on external HD

Tags: fedora, system-installation

I've been trying to install Fedora20 on my external HD, but have run into problems. Somehow I cannot choose the hard disk to install Fedora. Here is what I've done: First, I went and downloaded the .iso file from fedoraproject.org, then I erased my external HD and partitioned it (this all happened on windows 8). The external HD now has two partitions and some free space that I left alone. Of the initial 500GB, I now have partitioned

- 1GB to boot Fedora
- 370GB for general use
- 128GB left alone, unformatted

Booting Fedora from the ext. HD worked fine. So I tried to *install to hard drive*. That also works fine until I have to specify where to install Fedora. At this point I am shown the following disks
[image]
which shows my external HD as having 128GB free. But then I check that disk and press 'done', suddenly the following pops up
[image]
with 0B of free space and 0B of reclaimable space??
When I go to 'custom partitioning' and try to automatically set mount points, then I obtain an error message
[image]

What am I doing wrong? What should I do instead?

Comment: side note: 1GB is way too much for `/boot`.

Comment: @strugee: Good to know! But actually, I'm not talking about the /boot for custom partitioning, but rather the thingy needed for the installation which one can use on e.g. a USB stick instead of burning it on a CD/DVD (don't really know what the proper name for that is).

Comment: Oh, so you booted from the external drive - how did you make that bootable? Why not use a usb thumbdrive to put the installer or live-cd on like shown [here](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_Live_USB), then boot from that, once it's booted, use a tool like `gparted` to recreate the partition table on the external hdd then launch the install. Maybe just leaving the hdd unformatted but repartitioned will do the trick?

Comment: What you're doing seems to of been working with F19. http://www.zealfortechnology.com/2013/07/installation-guide-for-fedora-19.html

Comment: @illuminÉ: I created a small parition and used LiveUSB Creator, then used the "boot from USB/optical drive" (or something like that) option. That worked. For the more conventional way, I would have had to go out and buy a usb thumbdrive first. So I figured I would try without first. But I guess going out and buying one would have been quite a bit faster, in hindsight... ^^ Thanks for the comment.